Infinite dimensional version of Cauchy interlacing theorem
One formulation/application of the Cauchy interlacing theorem in finite dimensions could be written as follows.

Let $X$ be a finite dimensional, real Hilbert space. Let $Q \colon X \to X$ be a positive, self-adjoint operator. Suppose $Y \subset X$ is a finite-dimensional, real Hilbert subpace with codimension $k$. If $P \colon X \to Y$ denotes orthogonal projection onto $Y$ then
$$
\sup_{y \in Y, y \neq 0} \frac{\langle PQP^\ast y, y\rangle}{\langle y, y\rangle} \in [\lambda_{k+1}, \lambda_{1}], 
$$
where $\lambda_j$ denote the nonnegative eigenvalues of $Q$ arranged in nonincreasing order.

My question is: does this theorem still hold if we replace $X$ by an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space? In this case, what conditions on $(X, Y,  Q)$ are necessary for the result to hold?

If there is something deemed problematic in my post--I'd appreciate a question/clarification rather than downvoting needlessly...

Imho in order that the claim makes sense, $Q$ has to be assumed to be bounded and compact. If you then drop the requirements of finite-dimensionality for both $X$ and $Y$ then the claim should  be true.

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Compact_operators
